# IPtables : Limit number of new ssh connections per minute

Tags: linux, iptables

I need to ensure on my server that maximum new ssh connections per minute are not more then 5.

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 22 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 5 -j REJECT
```

Above IPtables rule work for me, but it will not allow new connections after one minute.

Any pointers how to achieve this?

Comment: This question has been [reposted on Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89413/iptables-limit-number-of-new-ssh-connections-per-minute) where it is on-topic.

Comment: @Gilles : Since It is not a migration : do you have reposted the answers :) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# SSH Anti-Bruteforce
# Next create a limiting rule. I limit to 3 hits in 60 seconds for ssh with this
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ssh-whitelist
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 3 --rttl --name SSH -j LOG --log-level info --log-prefix "Anti SSH-Bruteforce: "
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 3 --rttl --name SSH -j DROP
```

Comment: It's better to make logging and dropping packets in separate chain - more clean code and slightly better performance(you probably won't notice).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this as a bash script should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Window of time in seconds
SECS=100
# Max connections per IP
MAXCONN=10
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds ${SECS} --hitcount ${MAXCONN} -j DROP
```

This is an iteration of a common ruleset used to block brute force SSH attacks. The first rule makes sure a connecting IP address is added to a watchlist. The second rule tells iptables to check the watchlist and if the hitcount is exceeded to DROP the traffic.

Is this what you want? Not sure if you're looking for max connections of 5 per IP or 5 total for all IPs, which is not necessarily a good idea.

Comment: Well, IP in my case does not matter at all. If two IPs are attempting to connect to my machines, with 10 SSH connections each, then first 5 connections attempts should be allowed, regardless to its origin IP. After a minute, next bunch of 5 ips should be allowed. And so on.